# Performance planning - taking average requests per second and guessing peak

Tags: performance, http, web

If I have some predictions for average requests over time (say 1 per second) what models exist of predicting the peak?

I'm hoping to just plug in a number to some distribution (say normal) and pluck an estimate for the peak requests per second (since it won't be an actual uniform distribution with 1 request per second).

Answer (score 0):

I also read about prediction models some time ago. Some have a more scientific approach, but have a look, maybe these are helpful for you as well:

[Markov Model for Web Request prediction](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aOSPbNi54ETUJ%3apeople.cis.ksu.edu/~habel/MS_Report_Habel_Jul24_08.doc%20&hl=de&gl=de&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESh27Qe4-pftKCP04NEm-E_RhWOjl5qmNt6MAJ2deCLPOOUtj6awd2fORz8gUIDWwBSVBlAp_06UnljTGYcm6jKLETCIKtANDc8IAqdriKAbekQoaJVyJ-S5eRopUWILbWJ5DDue&sig=AHIEtbQwkFZwEoirhV9_J8Kg02kB-Fwb4w)

[Website traffic prediction](http://www.automotivedigitalmarketing.com/profiles/blogs/website-traffic-prediction)

[Study on internet traffic predicition models](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aKfiUo5NbQRQJ%3awww.ee.ktu.lt/journal/2007/6/11_ISSN_1392-1215_Study%2520on%2520Internet%2520Traffic%2520Prediction%2520Models_2007_V78_P_47-50.pdf%20&hl=de&gl=de&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESh2NndFkOYqtJEg4rtWxcRbGw3qOs7zhbC8atyT2gpKc2r67LQZFXR9S-GqjIVBwuMu0vmY-OCJ7wC9An5n5jab6vEpZmAwjf-k7zhZza50rRhDu8enj7CszfyUsr4-ejbChLVu&sig=AHIEtbRWFhZgQoDhms-BDKQc1IL5RgP-CQ)